# image error load placeholder image issue on mobile safari/chrome

Tags: jquery, image, function, attr, unbind

I am using the following script to load a placeholder image, if an image src png is not available/error's:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("img").error(function () {
    jQuery(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "/images/people_placeholder.png");
});
</script>
```

I am loading the above script just before the closing `</body>` tag.

It works fine on Chrome desktop & shows the placeholder image.

It doesn't work on Safari Desktop or on Mobile phone in Safari/Chrome

Any idea's?

Comment: Place it within the `<head />` element so that the handler can be attached before any images attempt to load.

Comment: @Cue But then `jQuery("img")` returns empty object and as `onerror` doesn't bubble, you can delegate it. So OP needs to capture it instead or maybe check for all images specific property

Comment: @A.Wolff yes that's correct, sorry I overlooked the delegation. With jQuery you can do `$(document).on('error', 'img', function () {});`

Comment: @Cue No, you cannot delegate `onerror` event **EDIT:** Oops sorry i see in my previous comment, it should be ***cannot delegate*** not ***can delegate***

Comment: @A.Wolff needs to be attached directly. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be because handler not called if `onerror` event already fired, you could try instead to capture `onerror` event, place this script just before `</head>` tag:

```
document.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
     var elm = event.target;
     if (elm.tagName == 'IMG') {
         elm.src = "/images/people_placeholder.png";
     }
 }, true ); // true to capture event
```

Or try checking for specific properties, you could use just before `</body>` tag:

```
jQuery("img").one('error', function () {
    jQuery(this).attr("src", "/images/people_placeholder.png"); //.unbind("error") is useless here
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete && !this.naturalHeight && !this.naturalWidth) {
        $(this).triggerHandler('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: 'jQuery("img").one'  i thing this is 'jQuery("img").on'

Comment: @Neophyte No using `one()` to avoid (for any reason as op was doing) to unbind the onerror event: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

Try This one

I found this Here [**Link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

```
function imgError(image) {
image.onerror = "";
image.src = "/images/people_placeholder.gif";
return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="image.png" onerror="imgError(this);"/>
```

Comment: this is fine, but requires the onerror="imgError(this);" added to each img tag

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="URL_OF_IMAGE" alt="image info" onerror="this.src='DEFAULT_IMG_URL'"/>
```

[check docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

or create Global Function to solve [this issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)